# angular express infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, url-routing

I have no idea why but my express/angular app is causing an infinite loop when loading the index page... I have my app setup:

```
app.configure(function() { 

    // set up our express application
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
    app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico')); 
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use(express.methodOverride());    
});
```

And my Angular app route provider:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularFileUpload', 'rcWizard', 'rcForm', 'rcDisabledBootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap']).
    config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $routeProvider
                .when("/login", { templateUrl: "/partials/login.ejs", controller: "LoginCtrl" })

                .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/login" });
        }
    ]);
```

My index.ejs file holding all the includes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form-styles/rcWizard.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css"/>

</head>
<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>

  <script src="javascripts/lib/helpers/sel_options.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/lib/helpers/xml2json.js"></script> 
  <script src="javascripts/lib/helpers/form-lib/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/lib/helpers/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/lib/helpers/form-src/directives/rcSubmit.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/lib/helpers/form-src/modules/rcForm.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/lib/helpers/form-src/modules/rcDisabled.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/lib/helpers/form-src/modules/rcWizard.js"></script>

  <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/services.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/directives.js"></script>

  <script src="javascripts/controllers/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally express:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('index');    
    });

    app.get('/partials/login.ejs', function (req, res) {
        res.render('/partials/login.ejs', { 'message': 'test 111' });
    });

    app.get('*', function(req, res){
        res.render('index');
    });
```

This seems really straightforward, but for some reason the server just continuously loads all the script files over and over again that are defined in my index.ejs file. All the examples I've seen set it up exactly this way... and I have tried multiple variations of paths, settings, etc. Does anything standout?

EDIT
here is my login.ejs partial:

```
<% include navbar_public.ejs %>

<div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <script>var message="<%-message%>";</script>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

        <h1 class="form-fonts"><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Login</h1>

        <!-- show any messages that come back with authentication -->
    <div ng-if="message.length > 0" class="alert alert-danger">{{message}}</div>


        <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
        <form action="/login" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="shimmy-button btn btn-success btn-lg">Login</button>
        </form>

        <hr>

        <p>Need an account? <a href="/signup">Signup</a></p>
        <p>Or go <a href="/">home</a>.</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Four things to explore:

1. You didn't include a copy of `/partials/login.ejs` so it's possible there's something in there that's causing the problem.
2. You are asking Angular's router to load /login when anything *but* /login is requested. This type of route setup can sometimes create infinite loops - try a different 'otherwise' as a test to help narrow down the issue.
3. For any request except these two URLs, you are rendering your index page. That means if the request comes in even slightly odd, it's going to dump out index all over again. Now, your index page has all those script and JS tags... Which leads me to:
4. You're using relative paths on many/most of your CSS/JS resources. You do not have a `BASE HREF` meta tag... That means when your browser is on `/login`, it's going to try to request these things as `/login/css/style.css` and so on. That *shouldn't* happen because this is only meant to be a partial at this point, but if any of the above items (or anything else) is going wrong, this is going to snowball.

I strongly recommend using your browser's Network panel and/or a debugging tool like Charles Proxy to review the exact sequence of requests your browser is issuing. That will almost certainly clue you in to the final issue.

If you're still having trouble and plan to reply back, please include the template for the login.ejs partial, and comments about unusual network requests. Please also talk more about how you know / why you say your app is infinite-looping and exactly where you suspect this is happening (server, client, both, etc.)

Comment: PS: I've done this to myself in the past with IFRAMEs, but the problem can be the same here with partials. If, when Angular goes to get that login.ejs, it somehow ends up with index.ejs, it's treating it as HTML. That will cause it to stick index.ejs inside the index.ejs already there, creating a nested level of duplicate code... And that's a REALLY common source of infinite loops in this kind of setup!